# English translation of Alei Shur (Rabbi Wolbe)

Tags: translation, mussar-ethics

I was wondering if anyone knows of an English translation of Alei Shur by Rabbi Wolbe? I have yet to find one.

Comment: [Welcome to MiYodeya](https://judaism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3887/11501) Raphael and thanks for this first question. Great to have you learn with us!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I also looked for a translation but never found one. I read R Wolbe asked for this sefer *not* to be translated into English (similar to R Moshe Feinstein with Igrot Moshe). This seems confirmed [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210411070129/https://mussarinstitute.org/courses-coming-soon/) and [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20220814150628/http://mypages.iit.edu/%7Ekbloom1/blog/Seforim_on_which_to_base_a_mussar_vaad.html).

The closest I found was [this audio translation](http://www.torahdownloads.com/shiur-1003918.html) by R Yoram Bogacz and translation excerpts [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20210308072037/https://mussarinstitute.org/alei-shur/).

Comment: Thanks! That's helpful to know and thanks for sharing the link to the audio classes.

Comment: Some of these links don't seem to work anymore...

Comment: @IsraelReader it is a pity, best you have now is my word and the fact that, at the time, the links were working and saying what I said they say - otherwise someone would have mentioned it. But it is clearly suboptimal. I dream of a Stackexchange which would automatically store a copy of the pages at the time the links were created

Comment: Did he give a reason? I feel like so many people could benefit from an English translation, I'm curious why he felt it was necessary that it not be produced.

Comment: @Yehuda for Igrot Moshe RMF was worried people would extract halacha straight from the answers without learning the sources. By restricting to Hebrew he was able at least to filter for more advanced learners. see https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/101532/11501

Comment: Sorry, I meant the Alei Shur - the R' Moshe's reasoning made sense to me ;)

Comment: @mbloch I was able to track down some of the links. Here they are: https://web.archive.org/web/20210411070129/https://mussarinstitute.org/courses-coming-soon/ and https://web.archive.org/web/20210308072037/https://mussarinstitute.org/alei-shur/ and https://web.archive.org/web/20220814150628/http://mypages.iit.edu/~kbloom1/blog/Seforim_on_which_to_base_a_mussar_vaad.html

Comment: @IsraelReader wonderful, I will edit now

Answer (score 0):

Feel free to also try: Shiurim going through vol 2 (entire volume not yet available):

https://open.spotify.com/show/3ZScyFS9Hz4adzaET7ov0w?si=915742ab06d745d8